# How get env from a custom file with nestjs?

Tags: database, mongoose, environment-variables, connection, nestjs

i'm trying to get env from this custom file

```
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';

export default registerAs('env', () => ({
  host: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
  port: 6000,
}));
```

and the following configuration on my mongoose module

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: config.get<string>('env.host'), // Loaded from .ENV
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

but nest print this error:`[Nest] 148967  - 06/11/2022, 19:04:40   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database.`

i tried with different configs, but i can't read my env.host

Comment: come on, the ever first snippet on the docs page about _configuration_ shows that you should call `ConfigModule.forRoot()`

Read this entirely: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#getting-started before posting any question, please.

Answer (score 0):

"If connecting fails on your machine, try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost"
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Are you sure that the problem is that your .env is not readed and it's not a db connection problem?

Did you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?